# how to check if bootstrap is available?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I want to use bootstrap in an application, but when I set the bootstrap theme via the xsp properties the framework is not loaded.

if I check the version of the extension library it says: 9.0.1.v00_00_20151122-0905

how can I check if the framework is available on this server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a good way to check it can be via the server console: tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.theme

you should get a list of available themes returned e.g.:

> tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.theme
>   2017-02-28 11:44:14   Framework is launched.
>   2017-02-28 11:44:14   id    State       Bundle
>   2017-02-28 11:44:14   27    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.theme.bootstrap_9.0.1.v00_17_20160428-0214
>   2017-02-28 11:44:14   262   ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.theme.oneui.idx_9.0.1.20151122-0905
>   2017-02-28 11:44:14   263   ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.theme.oneuiv302_9.0.1.20151122-0905

Answer (score 2):

That is the core 9.0.1 Extension Library. I believe it wasn't added until version 10 from OpenNTF (9.0.1.v00_10...). It will also be in FP8, which will be 9.0.1.v08_00.... The number before the "_" will be the feature pack version, the number after will be the OpenNTF release updating that release's Extension Library.

Answer (score 1):

In case this might help I have the following resources available on my local dev environment:

- Dojo
  http://dev1/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.9.7/dojo/dojo.js
- Bootstrap
  http://dev1/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/responsive/bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.min.js

Try to reach these resources on your server (mine is dev1).

If the lather one fails you presumably do not have bootstrap available.

But then I am on 9.0.1.v00_17_20160428-0214.

Shouldn't DDE have the panels 'Bootstrap' and 'Responsive'?

Try to have the Bootstrap4Xpages extension installed if you can: https://bootstrap4xpages.openntf.org/